# setuid not working as expected

Tags: centos7, setuid

I have a node js script that listens on a certain port.

If this script receives a json file it needs to execute a deploy script in a users home dir.

The node script runs under node_user.

The homedir is user_b.

I set up an acl so that user 'node_user' can access user 'user_b' dir and execute the deploy script.

setfacl -m u:node_user:rx deploy.sh

also set the uid on the deploy script so it should be execute under the user it is owned by (user_b):
chmod u+s deploy.sh

when i test it the deploy script is executed so sufficient rights there but the script is still being executes as node_user and not as its owner (user_b)

i verified this with:
watch -n1 'lsof | grep deploy.sh'

I'm wondering if anyone knows why it doesnt work as expected.

stat deploy.sh

```
  File: ‘deploy.sh’
  Size: 918             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 25242546    Links: 1
Access: (4750/-rwsr-x---)  Uid: ( 1003/ user_b)   Gid: ( 1005/ user_b)
```

getfacl deploy.sh:

```
# file: deploy.sh
# owner: user_b
# group: user_b
# flags: s--
user::rwx
user:node_user:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUID have no effect on scripts. This is by design.

Check [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/101265) for reference

Comment: Are you sure? /bin/passwd is a script and it has 4775.

Comment: `/bin/passwd` is actually `/usr/bin/passwd` and it is binary file

Comment: im on centos 7:
ls -al  /bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 27856 Aug  9  2019 /bin/passwd
but thats not the point, if setuid has no effect why is it being set on /binpasswd?
it is owned by root and if i execute it as a certain user it is executed by root.. exactly what in my understanding it should do... run as the user it is owned by, not as the user execting it

Comment: `/bin/passwd` is binary file. SUID do not have effect on shell, perl, python scripts

Comment: @chichi, and also check the directory `/bin`, `ls -ld /bin`

Comment: @chichi, you are correct about what SUID do. But this bit have effect only on binary files. Check the link I add to the answer

Comment: ok thx, i will rephrase the original question